# Saving a layout for later view

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I've created an app in which a user can can add or delete rows in a tableLayout. Inside of these rows, a user inputs an Academic class name, the letter grade received in the class, and the number of units the class is worth. Then, it calculates the user's gpa.

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this, but I need to save an exact copy of the layout when the user presses the 'save' button that will save every current specific thing. (Eg. number of editTexts, text in the editTexts, number of rows, etc.)

I've researched using SharedPreferences and using SQLite. I'm not sure which one is better for saving multiple specific layouts. Also, I know nothing of using SQLite because I've never used it before, so if that is the best choice, could you post a link or something to a good tutorial? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid database access you can just use simple 2d array to  Store all your data
Ex:

//Saving info of 1st Layout

```
String[][] data= new String[4][4];
data[0][0] =editTextno;
data[0][1] =editText;
data[0][2] =noofrows;
data[0][3] =field4;
```

For saving info of second,third you can similarly change the  index no. like `data[1]` for layout 1,`data[2]` for layout 2

later you can set this array inside SharedPreference or can create  setter getter  to  store this array and can retrieve the Array for info inputted by user wherever you want